# "A post type mismatch has been detected" Error when updating custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, errors

I have started getting this error when updating a custom post type on a clients site.  I've never seen this error before and can't find any reference to it in Google search.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a problem with the theme. Updating it to the latest version will solve the issue. A number of users have also faced [the same problem](https://themeforest.net/item/greenwich-language-school-wordpress-parallax-theme/21588731/comments) with a theme on Theme Forest. The developer has fixed it by releasing a new update. 
[image]

Comment: Well yes, it is an issue with the theme since the post type is registered in the theme.  There is not update for the theme however, which is why I'm asking on here.

Comment: OK. You can ask the developer of the theme to fix the issue through an updated version.